# .load() not executing to reload nav bar upon log in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

After the user logs in, I want the nav bar to change its "Log in" button to a "Log Out" button. After the user submits the correct username and password, I called `toggleLogInButton()`, which calls `.load()` to reload the nav bar. The "Congratulations" message shows up, but the log in button doesn't change. How do I fix this?

**login.php**

```
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<?php include "includes/navbar.php" ?> 
//some more code here
<?php
    if( password_verify( $password, $db_hashed_password ) ) {
        $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $username;
        echo ("Congratulations, $username! You logged in successfully!");
        echo "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'>toggleLogInButton();</script>";
    }
?>
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*Reload Log In button for nav bar */
    function toggleLogInButton() {
        $( ".right" ).load( "../includes/navbar.php .right" );
    }

});
```

**navbar.php**

```
<?php

echo ('<div class = "navBarWrapper">
        <div class="top bar">
            <ul class = "right float_right">');

            if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
                echo("<li class = 'buttons'> <a href = 'logout.php' class='otherPages'>Log Out</a></li>");
            } else {
                echo("<li class = 'buttons'> <a href = 'login.php' class='otherPages'>Login</a></li>");
            }

echo(       '</ul>
        </div> 
</div>');
?>
```

Comment: replace `echo "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'>toggleLogInButton();</script>";` with `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>toggleLogInButton();</script>";`

Comment: in login.php you're outputting script with source 'jquery'. It cause double jquery script on the page. Remove **src** from here

Comment: I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleLogInButton is not defined` and its pointing to an `echo` line outside the if statement that's a few lines above `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>toggleLogInButton();</script>"`;

Comment: @AlexSlipknot remove *src* from the script in head?

Comment: because you're defining this function on DomReady. So you can also wrap function with ready statement

Comment: what do you mean "wrap the function with ready statement "? I took it out of the dom ready statement and changed the file path slightly to `includes/navbar.php`. Based on printing to the console, `toggleLogInButton` runs, `$( ".right" ).load( "includes/navbar.php .right" );` is just not executing...

Answer (score 0):

In login.php you're outputting script with source 'jquery'. It cause double jquery script on the page. Remove src from here and wrap function in ready statement:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<?php include "includes/navbar.php" ?>
    //some more code here
<?php
if (password_verify($password, $db_hashed_password)) {
    $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $username;
    echo("Congratulations, $username! You logged in successfully!");
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { toggleLogInButton();})</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I moved `toggleLogInButton` outside `.ready` in main.js and used your suggestion `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { toggleLogInButton();})</script>";` in login.php. `toggleLogInButton` is called, but  `$( ".right" ).load( "includes/navbar.php .right" );` is NOT doing anything.

Comment: So load works but content does not appear with changes. And what do you see in network response? Maybe there is no content or you are loading content in wrong selector?